# What's the setpoint of the temperature on the primary side of a heat exchanger?

Tags: heat-transfer

I have a heat exchanger with known flows on priamry and secondary sides - $\dot m_p$, $\dot m_s$, known temperature in $t_{si}$  and a desired temperature out on the secondary side $t_{so}$. How to find the required $t_{pi}$ analytically? So far I've always done these calculations numerically with the excel solver.

This is where I get stuck in solving analytically - from the energy balance we find:

$$ t_{pi}=t_{po} - \frac{\dot m_s c_s}{\dot m_p c_p} * (t_{so} - t_{si})$$

but we need  $t_{po}$, when I try this (from the heat transfer equation) I think I'm stuck:

$$ t_{po} = \frac{kA \Delta T_m}{\dot m_p c_p} + t_{pi} $$

because to solve I'd need to extract my temperatures from the $ln$ in the denominator of $\Delta T_m$ and that's where I'd rather look in a textbook than do the math myself. Except my textbook (Perry) doesnt have that detail. $A$ is known and $k$ can be estiamted, so is known for the purpose of this questions.

So, **for given mass flows, and desired outlet temperature on the secondary side, what is the required inlet temperature on the primary side?**

The *ultimate* problem I want to solve is that I want to ask a question about HX control and I feel it would help to have this equation.

Comment: I don't think the units work for your equation for t_po. Also, you only state you know 1 out of the 4 temperatures needed, so you need more boundary conditions or more equations to match the number of unknowns.

Comment: What is the flow arrangement? counterflow ro parallel?

Comment: @J.Ari yes, I corrected. NMech  counter flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Background

Normally the process would go line this. Let's say the primary is hot, and the secondary is the cooler fluid.

The heat transfer rate $\dot{Q} = -\dot{Q}_p = \dot{Q}_s $. I.e.:

- The cooler fluid (s) gains
  $$\dot{Q} = m_s\cdot C_{p,s}(T_{s,o}- T_{s,i})  $$
- The hot fluid (p) loses:
  $$\dot{Q} = - m_p\cdot C_{p,p}(T_{p,o}- T_{p,i})  $$

Therefore the change in temperature is :

$$ T_{p,o}   = T_{p,i}- \frac{m_s\cdot C_{p,s}}{m_p\cdot C_{p,p}}(T_{s,o}- T_{s,i}) $$

Normally, if you get to that point then you need to calculate the length of the exchangerm and therefore the $A$ but since you know it I'll press on.

Here, I'm going to assume counterflow. At that point you need the *logarithmic mean temperature difference $\Delta T_{lm}$*. (please note that for different type of flows parallel, cross etc you need to change this).

$$\Delta T_{lm}  = \frac{\Delta T_1-\Delta T_2}{\ln (\Delta T_1/\Delta T_2)}$$

where:

- $\Delta T_1 = T_{p,i}-T_{s,o}$ : temperature difference at one exit
- $\Delta T_2 = T_{p,o}-T_{s,i}$ : temperature difference at other Exit

Then you can apply:

$$ kA\cdot\frac{\Delta T_1-\Delta T_2}{\ln (\Delta T_1/\Delta T_2)}= \dot{Q} =  m_s\cdot C_{p,s}(T_{s,o}-T_{s,i}) $$

$$ kA\cdot\frac{T_{p,i}-T_{s,o}-T_{p,o}+T_{s,i}}{\ln \left(\frac{T_{p,i}-T_{s,o}}{T_{p,o}-T_{s,i}}\right)}= \dot{Q}  $$

### Iterative solution

Here you can, solve with respect to $T_{p,i}$
$$ T_{p,i}-T_{s,o}-T_{p,o}+T_{s,i}= \frac{\dot{Q}}{kA\cdot} \ln \left(\frac{T_{p,i}-T_{s,o}}{T_{p,o}-T_{s,i}}\right) $$

$$ T_{p,i}= \frac{\dot{Q}}{kA} \ln \left(\frac{T_{p,i}-T_{s,o}}{T_{p,o}-T_{s,i}}\right) +T_{s,o}+T_{p,o}-T_{s,i}$$

From that point the easiest think of Excel is to iterate in order to find the solution (set a guess for $T_{p,i}$ apply it on the right hand, get a new $T_{p,i}'$, which you plug into the equation until $T_{p,i}-T_{p,i}' \rightarrow 0 $ ).

### close form solution

The other option if you need a close form solution (which is probably what you are asking), you can look at the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  In that case, you start from:

$$ kA\cdot\frac{\Delta T_1-\Delta T_2}{\ln (\Delta T_1/\Delta T_2)}= \dot{Q}$$

After replacing $\Delta T_1, \Delta T_2 $,the solution for $T_{p,i}$ takes the following form:

$$ T_{p,i} = T_{s,o} - \frac{ 
 Q }{A k} ProductLog[-\frac{A k(T_{p,o}-T_{s,i}) e^{-\frac{A k }{Q}(T_{p,o}-T_{s,i})  } }{Q}]$$

Where:

- $ProductLog[x]$ is the Lambert W function.

However Excel does not have this function builtin (at least to my knowledge). So you need to either do it another language/system (e.g. octave, or python) or find a macro for lambert w.

Comment: To be honest, I had never before heard of the lambert function and will need to take looong look at the WP article.

Comment: $T_{p,o}$ is not specified, so I'm not sure how you can make the iterative method work with two unknowns.

Comment: you can set any $T_{p,o}$ and find out what the $T_{p,i}$ should be. The system has a degree of freedom. It like trying to define x when x+ y =1.

Comment: Another value needs to be assumed, and that omission was what I was trying to highlight. I don't know if the W Lambert function method can handle two unknowns as I'm not schooled in this method.

Comment: Well, in that respect you are absolutely right. I omitted saying that you need to define the output temperature. I kind of thought it obvious. And also, with the Lambert W Function you need to make an assumption on either value $T_{p,o}$ or $T_{p,i}$